# Install Rdkit in jupyter notebook, using Anaconda enviornment

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda3, rdkit

How to install rdkit library in my jupyter notebook. I am using Anaconda environment.

[image]

Comment: Don't post pictures of error messages, copy paste them into your question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the anaconda environment, just run `conda install -c conda-forge rdkit`

You can find detailed installation instructions [here](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html).